# Checking for Timeout Error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, python-requests

So I have a pretty generic logging statement after a request:

```
try:
    r = requests.get(testUrl, timeout=10.0)
except Exception, err:
    logger.error({"message": err.message})
```

This works great for everything I've thrown at it except `TimeoutError`.  When the request times out the err I get back is a tuple that it tries and fails to serialize.

My question is how do I catch just this one type of error?  For starters `TimeoutError` is not something I have access to.  I have tried adding `from exceptions import *` but with no luck.  I've also tried importing `OSError` because the docs say `TimeoutError` is a subclass, but I was unable to access `TimeoutError` after importing `OSError`.

[TimeoutError docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TimeoutError)

I plan to either list my exceptions in order:

```
except TimeoutError, err:
     #handle this specific error
except Exception, err:
     #handle all other errors
```

or just check for type:

```
except Exception, err:
    if isinstance(err, TimeoutError):
        #handle specific error
    #handle all other errors
```

Python 2.7.3 & Django 1.5

Comment: `TimeoutError` is a custom exception provided by [the `requests` package](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#exceptions).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ahh, I thought it was the one referred to here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TimeoutError

Comment: When in doubt, print the `.__module__` attribute of an exception.

Comment: I came here for `TimeoutError` from `concurrent.futures`, which is just `concurrent.futures.TimeoutError`.

Comment: It is a bulletin in Python 3, but not in Python 2.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can handle [`requests.Timeout`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/4ecd74693f65821a96180af2859c13560bf84560/requests/exceptions.py#L46) exception:

```
try:
    r = requests.get(testUrl, timeout=10.0)
except requests.Timeout as err:
    logger.error({"message": err.message})
except requests.RequestException as err:
    # handle other errors
```

Example:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = "http://httpbin.org/delay/2"
>>> try:
...     r = requests.get(url, timeout=1)
... except requests.Timeout as err:
...     print(err.message)
... 
HTTPConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=1)
```

Comment: Pro tip: use http://httpbin.org/ to demonstrate specific response behaviour. There is a `http://httpbin.org/delay` route that'll respond after a configurable delay.