# Python Paramiko exec_command timeout doesn't work?

Tags: python, timeout, paramiko

I got the following ssh command,

```
    try:
        print 'trying to restart'
        self.ssh.exec_command(RR_CMD % (self.path_ext, self.rport), timeout=1)
        print 'restarted'
    except:
        self.ssh.close()
        self.ssh = ssh.create_ssh_client(self.ip, self.port, self. username, self.password)
        self.restart()
```

Basically I'm trying to restart a remote perl script.
But sometimes, like let's say 1 out of 2000 - my python program is freezing over the exec_command line for sometimes up to a few minutes!

I would like to use the timeout function, which I set to 1 second, but it doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 6):

I've had issues with the timeout in exec_command not being honored how I would anticipate. For example, I had the timeout set to 60 and found a hung command running all night. What I was doing before was

```
response = client.exec_command(command, timeout=60)
returncode = response[0].channel.recv_exit_status()
```

But with a timeout of None or any value, it was hanging on `recv_exit_status`, Now, instead, I am just managing the timeout myself, since `exec_command` is non-blocking, by polling `channel.exit_status_ready`.

```
start = time.time()
while time.time() < start + timeout:
    if response[0].channel.exit_status_ready():
        break
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    raise TimeoutError(f'{command} timed out on {hostname}')
returncode = response[0].channel.recv_exit_status()
```

Comment: Thanks! A question: where to import `TimeoutError`?

Comment: @FaithReaper -  it's a builtin

Comment: Yes. Builtin in Py3, but not in Py2. I just found that. See this if you are using Python 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210792/checking-for-timeout-error-in-python

Answer (score 0):

What about your version of `paramiko`?

The latest version of `paramiko` supported argument `timeout`.

[Paramiko Changelog](http://www.paramiko.org/changelog.html) v1.10.0:

> Add timeout parameter to SSHClient.exec_command for easier setting of the command’s internal channel object’s timeout. Thanks to Cernov Vladimir for the patch.

Comment: My version is 1.16, and I indeed use the timeout command, it juts doesnt timeout at all...

Answer (score 0):

For those who use recv_exit_status:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('192.168.10.1', username='root', password='password')
_, out, err = ssh.exec_command("python3 -c 'from time import sleep\nsleep(5)'")

# this
# print(out.channel.recv_exit_status())
# change this to
out.channel.status_event.wait(timeout=10)  # < 5 raise assert
assert out.channel.status_event.is_set()
print(out.channel.exit_status)
ssh.close()
print("end script")
```