# Kill remote session after certain time, if no response from command launched on remote server using Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am having some trouble with Paramiko module while running a command on remote server.

```
def check_linux(cmd, client_ip, client_name):
    port = 22
    username = 'xxxxxxx'
    password = 'xxxxxxxx'
    try:
        sse = paramiko.SSHClient()
        sse.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        sse.connect(client_ip, port, username, password, timeout=5)
        (stdin, stdout, stderr) = sse.exec_command("my cmd")
        del stdin
        status = stdout.read()
        status = status.decode('ascii')
        return status
    except (paramiko.SSHException, socket.error, socket.timeout, Exception) as error:
        print "Unable to Authenticate/logon:" ,client_name,client_ip,
        sys.exit()
```

```
[root@xxxxxxx star_script]# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 11 2015, 17:47:16)
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import paramiko
>>> port = 22
>>> username = 'xxxxxxxx'
>>> password = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
>>> client_ip = 'xxxxxxx'
>>> cmd = 'openssl s_client -connect xxxxxxx:xxxxx'
>>> sse = paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> sse.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>>> sse.connect(client_ip, port, username, password, timeout=5)
>>> (stdin, stdout, stderr) = sse.exec_command(cmd)
>>> status = stderr.read()
```

For some server's, command execution doesn't happen and the program is not executing further. I've tried `readlines()` and `stdout.channel.eof_received`, but both seems to be not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.read` will wait until the command finishes, what it never does.

Instead, wait for the command to finish first. If it is taking too long, kill the command (using `stdout.channel.close()`).

You can use the code from [Python Paramiko exec_command timeout doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35403031/850848):

```
timeout = 30
import time
endtime = time.time() + timeout
while not stdout.channel.eof_received:
    time.sleep(1)
    if time.time() > endtime:
        stdout.channel.close()
        break
status = stdout.read()
```

---

Though you can use the above code, only if the command produces very little output. Otherwise the code might deadlock. For a robust solution, you need to read the output continuously.
See [A command does not finish when executed using Python Paramiko exec_command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61895403/850848)

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin. It works!..I accept the answer!.. Thanks again.