# A command does not finish when executed using Python Paramiko exec_command

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, callback, paramiko

I've got a Python program which sits on a remote server which uploads a file to an AWS bucket when run. If I ssh onto the server and run it with the command `sudo python3 /path/to/backup.py` it works as expected.

I'm writing a Python program to automate a bigger process which includes running backup.py. I created a function to do this using the paramiko library. This is where the command gets run

```py
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = self.ssh.exec_command('sudo python3 /path/to/backup.py', 1800)
logging.debug(f'ssh_stdout: {ssh_stdout.readline()}')
logging.debug(f'ssh_stderr: {ssh_stderr.readline()}')
```

My automation gives me this output:

```
ssh_stdout: Tue, 19 May 2020 14:36:43 INFO     The COS endpoint is 9.11.200.206, writing to vault: SD_BACKUP_4058
```

The program doesn't do anything after that. When I log onto the server and check the logs of `backup.py`, I can see that it is still running and seems to be sitting at the file upload. This is the code it's stuck at:

```py
s3_client.upload_file(
    Filename=BACKUP,
    Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
    Key=SPLIT_FILE_NAME,
    Callback=pp(BACKUP),
    Config=config)
```

I can't understand why it's getting stuck here when started by my automation program and not when I run it from a command line in the terminal. I can't see anything in the logs which help me. It just seems to be stuck at that point in its execution. Could it be something to do with the callback not getting returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read only one line of the output.

```
logging.debug(f'ssh_stdout: {ssh_stdout.readline()}')
```

If the remote program produces lot of output, as soon as its output buffer fills in, the program hangs on the next attempt to write some output.

---

If you want the program to finish, you have to keep reading the output.

The simplest way is to use `readlines` or `read`:

```
print(stdout.read())
```

But that's inefficient for large outputs like yours.

Instead you can read the output line by line:

```
for line in stdout:
    print(line.strip())
```

---

It gets more complicated, when the commands produces also an error output, as then you have to read both output streams.
See [Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/850848).

And you should check the error output in any case, for good error handling. See also:
[Command executed with Paramiko does not produce any output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56066517/850848)